# How to find a file in linux from terminal window

Tags: linux

Actually i want to search a file which is located some where in the system. Im having debian linux and i need to search using terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `find` command, for example

```
find . -name "foo.*"
```

to search for all files named `foo.*` in the current directory.

Here is the [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) documentation.